# Google Script Trigger for Debt Tracker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am building a debt tracker currently I have listed all the unpaid debts in column C and labeled them “Unpaid” in column E. However if I type “paid” in column E I want whatever is in the row of column C to change to 0 or $0 (adjacent).

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSQCl6n1wnxN_uiZEzRoITEvpB29UErrcbMxnkb6SBE/edit?usp=sharing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jimDl.jpg)

**User Story**

GIVEN the user pays debt

IF the user type "paid" (in column E)

THEN The amount owned changes to 0

Comment: Hey is ColC a manual an entry or data pull from another sheet?

Answer (score 1):

#### Clear C is E is paid

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Your sheet name' && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "paid") {
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(0).setNumberFormat("#,##0.00;(#,##0.00")
  }
}
```